how to split div into 2 parts and each part will not give in their width?
My goal is to split a div into 2 equal parts.
The problem is that when one part require wider width, the other part give in.
Note:

the VerylongtextVerylongtextVerylongtext is intentionally wrapped with <div> to simulate wrapped by a button.

stackblitz: https://jsfiddle.net/j7wd4x3k/
<div style="display: flex">
  <!-- Left -->
  <div style="background: yellow; flex: 1 0 0">
    <div class="ellipsis">
      VerylongtextVerylongtextVerylongtext
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Right -->
  <div style="background: red; flex: 1 0 0">
    Right
  </div>
</div>

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


Can you elaborate on the problem like you want to divide a div in equal parts, like in what way. Do you want to divide width between the child components or you want half of the elements to occupy 50% and other other half

You could use width: 50% on both of your children

@masteronin99 I want to divide width between the child components equally. Anyway, I think both of your question holds true for my problem.

What you need is min-width:0 on the flex items: https://jsfiddle.net/nhwzxgse/

Using width on Flexbox is not a good idea. We have flex-basis for it.


.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div style="display: flex">
  <!-- Left -->
  <div style="background: yellow; display:flex; flex-basis: 50%; max-width: 50%">
    VerylongtextVerylongtextVerylongtext
  </div>
  <!-- Right -->
  <div style="background: red; display:flex; flex-basis: 50%; max-width: 50%">
    Right
  </div>
</div>




Remove flex: 1 0 0 in your CSS and replace with width: 50%; - that should do the trick :)

You can use Bootstrap class="col-6" for two part separate, follow the bellow code example.
<div class="row">

    <!-- Left Column -->
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="party">Party</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="party">
                <option value="">Option 1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Right Column -->
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tat">Loom</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tat">
                <option value="">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

